# IOS not loading iframe or xml content

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iframe

I am trying to get the contents of a iframe on IOS my code works on every other browser and phone ("IE, chrome, edge, and android chrome") I have used except on my iPod (safari and chrome) here is my code

```
var ifr = "<iframe id='ifr' src='"+ url +"' style='display:none;'></iframe>"
        document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML = ifr;
        var iframe = document.getElementById("ifr");
        iframe.onload = function (){
        var responseData = iframe.contentDocument.body.innerText;
        //Do stuff with responseData
        }
```

So... I changed my code to xml and it still is doing the same thing.